# Python: Compare three numpy arrays with different size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 diferent arrays (lets call them arrya, arryb and arryc). arrya and arryb have the same size, arryc is quite smaller.

What I'm trying to do is to get the first coincidence in arrya or arryb (excluding) with arryc.For Instance:

```
arrya = [100,25,56,78,90,52,13]
arryb = [93,42,52,25,10,11,24]
arryc = [52,13,24,100]
```

In this case I'd need the result that the first coincidence is between arrayc in index 4 with arrya in index 0.

I've tried with loops, but having diferent sizes, i get the error "index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4". I've tried also

Comment: Python is `0`-index. So `100` is at index `3` of `arryc`...

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays.  Be consistent in your description. And show the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use intersections. An intersection shows which values are common between two arrays. Numpy has an intersect1d function that can be used on lists or numpy arrays. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html

```
import numpy as np

arrya = [100,25,56,78,90,52,13]
arryb = [93,42,52,25,10,11,24]
arryc = [52,13,24,100]

# An intersection returns values that are common between the two arrays
# return_indices arg is new in version 1.15.0
common_vals, ida, idc = np.intersect1d(arrya, arryc, return_indices=True)

print(f'These are common values between A and C {common_vals}')

print(f'These are indices in A {ida}')

print(f'These are indices in C {idc}')
```

Then from these arrays you can check if they are empty and use the first instance found.

```
if len(ida) > 0:
    print(f'First coincidental index found between arrayA and arrayC, is arrayA index {ida[0]}')
```

Comment: Thank you so much it seems the appropiate solution.

Comment: Glad to help. Please select my answer if this works for you.